# port number of HTTP server

Tags: apache, tcp, linux-kernel

I try to access the apache server on another machine (Even at localhost). I used

wireshark to get the port number of the packets which are random port number vs 80. This is correct.

But at the mean time, I tried to print out the port number at in the kernel myself at ip_rcv() which tcph->source and tcph->dest. It turned out that these two port numbers are 
also random.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, can anybody tell me where I can get the correct port number from kernel?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do in the kernel and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the port number from any kernel, to set the port number for a Linux web-server do the following if you have apache:

- If you have `Apache`, then go to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and change the `80` to a desired number of your choice
- Then restart your server with `service apache2 restart`
- Then in the web browser of your choice go to `http://SERVER-IP:portnumber`

NOTE: If you change the port number from 80 you must enter the new port number after the url/IP.

Comment: I got the solution:

__be16 osport = 0, odport = 0;

struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

const struct tcphdr *tcph= (struct tcphdr *)((__u32 *)iph + iph-
>ihl); 

osport = htons((unsigned short int) tcph->source);

odport = htons((unsigned short int) tcph->dest);